# How to create Async[Future] from Async[IO]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, doobie

I am trying to implicitly add Async and Sync in my code for doobie repository. The Sync and Async[F] works fine IO. I want to convert them to Future and facing problem

I have tried to create my own Aync from  IO

```
def futureAsync(implicit F: MonadError[Future, Throwable]): Async[Future] = new Async[Future] {
    override def async[A](k: (Either[Throwable, A] => Unit) => Unit): Future[A] = IO.async(k).unsafeToFuture()

    override def asyncF[A](k: (Either[Throwable, A] => Unit) => Future[Unit]): Future[A] =
      throw new Exception("Not implemented Future.asyncF")

    override def suspend[A](thunk: => Future[A]): Future[A] = thunk

    override def bracketCase[A, B](acquire: Future[A])(use: A => Future[B])(release: (A, ExitCase[Throwable]) => Future[Unit]): Future[B] =
      throw new Exception("Not implemented Future.bracketCase")

    override def raiseError[A](e: Throwable): Future[A] = F.raiseError(e)

    override def handleErrorWith[A](fa: Future[A])(f: Throwable => Future[A]): Future[A] = F.handleErrorWith(fa)(_ => f(new Exception("")))

    override def pure[A](x: A): Future[A] = F.pure(x)

    override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => Future[B]): Future[B] = F.flatMap(fa)(f)

    override def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Future[Either[A, B]]): Future[B] = F.tailRecM(a)(f)
  }
```

I am struck with implementation of two functions in there asyncF and bracketCase
Can some one help?

Comment: I think that's simply impossible, because `Sync` means synchronous suspend. And `Future` cannot suspend, it executes immediately. So you can write these instances, they will typecheck, but your resulting `Async` will have the wrong semantics. https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/

Answer (score 16):

As Reactormonk says in a comment above, it's not possible to write an instance of `Async` for `Future` that has the right semantics, because `Async` extends `Sync`, and `Sync` requires a representation of a computation that can be run repeatedly, while Scala's futures begin running when they're defined and can't be re-run.

### An unlawful instance

It's instructive to see this for yourself, though, and I'd encourage you to try to write your own compile-able but (necessarily) unlawful `Async[Future]` instance without looking at the next block of code. For the sake of the example, though, here's a quick sketch off the top of my head:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import cats.effect.{Async, ExitCase, IO}

def futureAsync(implicit c: ExecutionContext): Async[Future] = new Async[Future] {
  def async[A](k: (Either[Throwable, A] => Unit) => Unit): Future[A] =
    IO.async(k).unsafeToFuture()

  def asyncF[A](k: (Either[Throwable, A] => Unit) => Future[Unit]): Future[A] = {
    val p = Promise[A]()
    val f = k {
      case Right(a) => p.success(a)
      case Left(e) => p.failure(e)
    }
    f.flatMap(_ => p.future)
  }

  def suspend[A](thunk: => Future[A]): Future[A] = Future(thunk).flatten

  def bracketCase[A, B](acquire: Future[A])(use: A => Future[B])(
    release: (A, ExitCase[Throwable]) => Future[Unit]
  ): Future[B] = acquire.flatMap { a =>
    use(a).transformWith {
      case Success(b) => release(a, ExitCase.Completed).map(_ => b)
      case Failure(e) => release(a, ExitCase.Error(e)).flatMap(_ => Future.failed(e))
    }
  }

  def raiseError[A](e: Throwable): Future[A] = Future.failed(e)
  def handleErrorWith[A](fa: Future[A])(f: Throwable => Future[A]): Future[A] =
    fa.recoverWith { case t => f(t) }

  def pure[A](x: A): Future[A] = Future.successful(x)
  def flatMap[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => Future[B]): Future[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
  def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Future[Either[A, B]]): Future[B] = f(a).flatMap {
    case Right(b) => Future.successful(b)
    case Left(a) => tailRecM(a)(f)
  }
}
```

This will compile just fine, and would probably work for some situations (but please don't actually use it!). We've said it can't have the right semantics, though, and we can show that by using cats-effect's laws module.

### Checking the laws

First we need some boilerplate-y stuff you don't really need to worry about:

```
import cats.kernel.Eq, cats.implicits._
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary

implicit val throwableEq: Eq[Throwable] =  Eq.by[Throwable, String](_.toString)
implicit val nonFatalArbitrary: Arbitrary[Throwable] =
  Arbitrary(Arbitrary.arbitrary[Exception].map(identity))

implicit def futureEq[A](implicit A: Eq[A], ec: ExecutionContext): Eq[Future[A]] =
  new Eq[Future[A]] {
    private def liftToEither(f: Future[A]): Future[Either[Throwable, A]] =
      f.map(Right(_)).recover { case e => Left(e) }

      def eqv(fx: Future[A], fy: Future[A]): Boolean =
        scala.concurrent.Await.result(
        liftToEither(fx).zip(liftToEither(fy)).map {
          case (rx, ry) => rx === ry
        },
        scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(1, "second")
      )
  }
```

Then we can define a test that checks the `Async` laws for our instance:

```
import cats.effect.laws.discipline.{AsyncTests, Parameters}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.typelevel.discipline.scalatest.Discipline

object FutureAsyncSuite extends FunSuite with Discipline {
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global

  implicit val params: Parameters =
    Parameters.default.copy(allowNonTerminationLaws = false)

  checkAll(
    "Async",
    AsyncTests[Future](futureAsync).async[String, String, String]
  )
}
```

And then we can run the law tests:

```
scala> FutureAsyncSuite.execute()
FutureAsyncSuite:
- Async.async.acquire and release of bracket are uncancelable
- Async.async.ap consistent with product + map
- Async.async.applicative homomorphism
...
```

You'll see that most of the tests are green; this instance gets a lot of things right.

### Where it breaks the law

It does show three failed tests, though, including the following:

```
- Async.async.repeated sync evaluation not memoized *** FAILED ***
  GeneratorDrivenPropertyCheckFailedException was thrown during property evaluation.
   (Discipline.scala:14)
    Falsified after 1 successful property evaluations.
    Location: (Discipline.scala:14)
    Occurred when passed generated values (
      arg0 = "淳칇멀",
      arg1 = org.scalacheck.GenArities$$Lambda$7154/1834868832@1624ea25
    )
    Label of failing property:
      Expected: Future(Success(驅ṇ숆㽝珅뢈矉))
  Received: Future(Success(淳칇멀))
```

If you look at the [laws definitions](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/v2.0.0-M1/laws/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/laws/SyncLaws.scala#L47), you'll see that this is a test that defines a `Future` value with `delay` and then sequences it multiple times, like this:

```
val change = F.delay { /* observable side effect here */ }
val read = F.delay(cur)

change *> change *> read
```

The other two failures are similar "not memoized" violations. These tests should see the side effect happen twice, but in our case it's not possible to write `delay` or `suspend` for `Future` in such a way that that would happen (it's worth trying, though, to convince yourself that this is the case).

### What you should do instead

To sum up: you can write an `Async[Future]` instance that will pass something like 75 of the 78 `Async` laws tests, but it's not possible to write an instance that will pass all of them, and using an unlawful instance is a really bad idea: both potential users of your code and libraries like Doobie will assume that your instances are lawful, and if you don't live up to this assumption you're opening the door to complex and annoying bugs.

It's worth noting that it's not too hard to write a minimal wrapper for `Future` that has a lawful `Async` instance (for example I've got a wrapper for Twitter's future called `Rerunnable` in my [catbird](https://github.com/travisbrown/catbird) library). You really should just stick with `cats.effect.IO`, though, and use the provided conversions to convert to and from futures in any parts of your code where you're working with traditional `Future`-based APIs.